# Error install numpy getting requirements to build wheel

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, installation

I have tried installing but I get the following error

```
PS C:\Users\Georgina Zeron> pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.25.2.tar.gz (10.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [40 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          backend = _build_backend()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
          obj = import_module(mod_path)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\Georgina Zeron\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9flerb5q\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 242, in <module>
          monkey.patch_all()
        File "C:\Users\Georgina Zeron\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9flerb5q\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 99, in patch_all
          patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
        File "C:\Users\Georgina Zeron\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9flerb5q\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 162, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
          patch_func(*msvc9('find_vcvarsall'))
        File "C:\Users\Georgina Zeron\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9flerb5q\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 149, in patch_params
          mod = import_module(mod_name)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\Georgina Zeron\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9flerb5q\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in <module>
          raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

e above for details.

```
I have tried with numpy==1.18 and I get to the requirements but the following happens
```

PS C:\Users\Georgina Zeron> pip install numpy==1.18 --no-build-isolation
Collecting numpy==1.18
Using cached numpy-1.18.0.zip (5.4 MB)
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [41 lines of output]
Running from numpy source directory.
:425: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
Processing numpy/random_bounded_integers.pxd.in
Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Georgina Zeron\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4lizvqul\numpy_0505c99be39549bbaed18726861293cb\tools\cythonize.py", line 61, in process_pyx
from Cython.Compiler.Version import version as cython_version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'

```
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Georgina Zeron\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4lizvqul\numpy_0505c99be39549bbaed18726861293cb\tools\cythonize.py", line 238, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\Georgina Zeron\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4lizvqul\numpy_0505c99be39549bbaed18726861293cb\tools\cythonize.py", line 234, in main
      find_process_files(root_dir)
    File "C:\Users\Georgina Zeron\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4lizvqul\numpy_0505c99be39549bbaed18726861293cb\tools\cythonize.py", line 225, in find_process_files
      process(root_dir, fromfile, tofile, function, hash_db)
    File "C:\Users\Georgina Zeron\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4lizvqul\numpy_0505c99be39549bbaed18726861293cb\tools\cythonize.py", line 191, in process
      processor_function(fromfile, tofile)
    File "C:\Users\Georgina Zeron\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4lizvqul\numpy_0505c99be39549bbaed18726861293cb\tools\cythonize.py", line 66, in process_pyx
      raise OSError('Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module')
  OSError: Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module
  Cythonizing sources
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 149, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 380, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 450, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 433, in setup_package
    File "<string>", line 240, in generate_cython
  RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: Se

Comment: this looks like windows, so should be `python -m pip install numpy`.  what did you do ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing ok! To be fair there could be a lot of reasons behind this error. I can suggest you first update the next packages and then install numpy:

```bash
# no cache is necessary flag so it won't use the local copy of the package that could be corrupted

pip install -U setuptools --no-cache-dir
pip install -U wheel --no-cache-dir

pip install -U numpy --no-cache-dir
```

Also from my experience, I suggest you not use a global environment but rather use some virtual environment. It could be standard `venv` or `poetry` or `conda` or `mamba` etc, then all packages will be isolated which is good.